# Multiple series forecasting at once using statsmodels (SARIMAX)

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

My model is a [SARIMAX](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) model from the [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/index.html) package, with the following order (p,0,0), no seasonal component and no exogenous inputs. The model is trained to make "one-step ahead predictions" using a time series.

I want to test the forecasting ability (at a given prediction horizon) of my model. To do so, I have hundreds of tinier time series, my evaluation set, for which I do the following:

- I create a new model and apply the [filter](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.filter.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.filter) function with the fitted model's parameters
- I run the [forecast](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEResults.forecast) function at a prediction horizon of my choice

While it does work, and is quite fast per forecasting (100ms), it ends up being really slow when run on the entire set of evaluation time series.

My question is the following: **How to run the forecasting task by batches (and not one by one), as one would do with any machine learning model from the scikit-learn package ?**

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I have got exactly the same problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: Sadly, not really. At the moment, instead of using the filter/forecast functions, I use the apply/forecast functions. I believe the apply function is only available in the current non-stable release statsmodels 0.12.0.dev0.